# Delphi: Indy - how to get the response body on error?

Tags: delphi, http, httpresponse, indy

Delphi6 and XE3.

I want to get the real response body of a request.
But the server makes error 500.
Then the Indy replace the response text with the description of the error.

This homepage is designed for answer 500 in non abnormal operations too, and we need to determine what to do from response text.

Could I get the response text from IdHTTP or from an Exception object when the status code is 500?

Thanks for any info!

Comment: for XE3. It's interesting that EIdHTTPProtocolException's FErrorMessage contains the response, but I couldn't access it... :-(

Comment: @durumdara: Why could you not access it? `EIdHTTPProtocolException.ErrorMessage` is a public property.

Comment: It's my mistake... I used E.Message instead of E.ErrorMessage but I everytime missed... :-(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When `TIdHTTP` encounters a server error, it raises an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception, where its `ErrorCode` property contains the HTTP status code (500, etc), its `Message` property contains the HTTP status text ("Internal Error", etc), and its `ErrorMessage` property contains the body text of the response, if any.  So, for example:

```
try
  IdHTTP1.Get(...);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
    // use E.ErrorCode, E.Message, and E.ErrorMessage as needed...
  end;
end;
```